swagger returns 403 error even though object not found
`@PostMapping("/insert")
@Operation(summary = "Создать раздел и подразделы")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Bearer Authentication")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Раздел/подраздел успешно создан/обновлен"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Требуется авторизация"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Не найден объект", content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ExceptionDto.class))}),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Внутренняя ошибка", content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ExceptionDto.class))})})
public List<Section> insert(@RequestBody @Validated @NotNull Section dto) {
    return sectionService.insertSection(dto);
}

@Transactional
public Section insertSection(@NotNull Section dto) {
    if (dto.getId() != null && (!sectionRepository.existsById(dto.getId()))) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Section not found");
    }
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    Section section = new Section();
    section.setId(dto.getId());
    section.setCode(uuid.toString());
    section.setSectionName(dto.getSectionName());
    return sectionRepository.save(section);
}`

Why does swagger throw a 403 error? And in the application logs it says that the section is not found. How to make swagger show this error
ExceptionDto.class <- RuntimeException
I tried to put 400, 403, 404 error in errors

You have an @SecurityRequirement annotation that attempts to enforce the security level of the insert method.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#securityrequirement
https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/security/SecurityRequirement.html
